# What happen if other users make edit on someone's answer?

Tags: support, reputation, edits, suggested-edits, notifications

I am just curious, because I've neither edited someone's answer nor my answer is edited by other users.

What happen to the user who answered to the question if other user try to edit their answer? Any notification or approvement from the original user or it will be peer-reviewed? Is someone who edited the answer get the reputation points to the answer onwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The post owner will get a notification when their post has been edited, or there is a pending suggested edit. Users above 2000 reputation ([less on beta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared)) can edit directly, suggested edits from users below 2000 reputation must be reviewed. The post owner can reject or approve suggested edits, but they will also be put in the peer-review queue. On large sites like Stack Overflow, the post will often have been reviewed by others before the owner sees their notification.

Reputation for votes on posts is always awarded to the post owner. The editor will only receive +2 reputation for each approved suggested edit (up to a maximum of +1000 reputation).

Comment: +1 So, there is rep point for approved-suggested-edited on answer too. I only think this only happen on editing a question. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @WayanWiprayoga You're welcome. :) The suggested edit system is described in detail in [How do suggested edits work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251).

Comment: The link is useful, Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

If your answer is edited by 2K+ user, you only get notification about it. Editing and suggested editing on answers works same as in question. If your answer is edited by less than 2K reputation user you get notification to review it.

Notification when your answer is edited:

[image]

Notification when an edit is suggested on your answer (or question):

[image]

A user who edited the answer doesn't get/lose any reputation for any upvotes/downvotes on answers. However the editor gain 2 reputation for suggesting edit if he has not crossed 1000 reputation boundary.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the explaination. So, the 2000+ rep-user can edit without been peer-reviewed?

Comment: @WayanWiprayoga - Yes of course. If you think the edit is invalid you can rollback the edit.